# TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert / values

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am trying to insert data into a table and getting the error
`"Unable to create temp file for insert values expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values"`. My table structure is:

```
create table test(nm string,file string,status string, start_ts timestamp,add_ts timestamp)
```

...and the error occurs when I try to insert data into it like this:

```
Insert into test values("bab","text","completed",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20210310.190541','yyyyMMDdd.HHmmss')));
```

What is TOK_FUNCTION and why the above insert is throwing an error?

Comment: `TOK` probably short form of Tokenize. But i am not 100% sure. I have seen this issue mostly related to syntax, data type mismatch - everywhere. Also, your selct clause has issues - if you are looking to convert seconds to date time - you need to sue `from_unixtime(20210310, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a')` - Pls note this accepts `BIGINT`.

Comment: Thanks Koushik for your response. Looks like issue with function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in insert statement. I am not sure why we can't use this function in insert statement.  Any idea?

Comment: What is your hive version ?  Hive 1.2.0 and higher uses CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. If its lower, you can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`.